# Keep only selected keys in every object from array

Tags: javascript

In the below, function `redux1` removes entries corresponding to keys not listed in `keys_to_keep` from `data` object.

Given that I have a list of object keys to keep, how can I rewrite `redux1` in a cleaner way, prefarably utilizing `map`, `filter` or `reduce`?

```js
var data = [
    {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
    {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
    {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
    {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city']

function redux1(data) {
    data.forEach((person) => {
        Object.keys(person).forEach((key) => {
            if (!keys_to_keep.includes(key)) {
                delete (person[key])
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(data)
}

function redux2(data) { 
    var reduced = data.filter(person => Object.keys(person).filter(key => keys_to_keep.includes(key)))
    console.log(reduced)
}

redux1(data)
//redux2(data)
```

My current `redux2` will return objects will not remove `age`.

Comment: _"...in a cleaner way"_ - what's not "clean" about your function? _"...prefarably utilizing map, filter or reduce?"_ - Why those three?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, not a duplicate. I know this answer, but it only covers deleting specific key, not all keys not found in an array.

Comment: Then you should mention that in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Closely related: [Extract certain properties from all objects in array](/q/52153345/4642212).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [
 {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
 {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
 {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
 {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

const keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city'];

const redux = array => array.map(o => keys_to_keep.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = o[curr];
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(redux(data));
```

Answer (score 9):

A version slightly shorter than the accepted answer using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = [
    {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
    {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
    {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
    {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

const keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city'];

const redux1 = list => list.map(o => Object.fromEntries(
    keys_to_keep.map(k => [k, o[k]])
));

console.log(redux1(data));
```

Comment: Thanks. Useful :) I need also an exclusion. Pasted from your code with field excluded : `data.map(o => Object.fromEntries( Object.keys(o).filter((n) =>  ["age"].indexOf(n) < 0 ).map(k => [k, o[k]]) ))`

Comment: @phili_b You could directly filter the `entries` instead of adding another map: `Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => !["age"].includes(k) ) )`

Comment: Ha yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 3):

use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and Array.forEach inside it :

```js
var data = [
 {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
 {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
 {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
 {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city']

const result = data.map(e => {
  const obj = {};
  keys_to_keep.forEach(k => obj[k] = e[k])
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
 {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
 {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
 {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
 {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

var keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city']

data=data.map(element => Object.assign({}, ...keys_to_keep.map(key => ({[key]: element[key]}))))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce((r, c) => [ ...r, Object.entries(c).reduce((b, [k, v]) => keys_to_keep.includes(k) ? {...b, [k]: v } : b, {}) ],[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries`

```js
function objfilter(data,keys_to_keep){
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(a=>keys_to_keep.includes(a[0])))
}
const data = [
    {name: 'John', city: 'London', age: 42},
    {name: 'Mike', city: 'Warsaw', age: 18},
    {name: 'Jim', city: 'New York', age: 22},
    {name: 'Celine', city: 'Tokyo', age: 54},
]

const keys_to_keep = ['name', 'city'];

console.log(objfilter(data,keys_to_keep))
```