# How to remove another keys of object in array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an **array object** same like below and I want to get the result only 3 keys **id**, **token** and **name**:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  token: 'xyz',
  name: 'john',
  _v: 2,
  _isActived: true,
  _isBlocked: false,
  ...
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  token: 'abc',
  name: 'thomas',
  _v: 2,
  _isActived: true,
  _isBlocked: false,
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

My desired result:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  token: 'xyz',
  name: 'john'
 },
 {
  id:2,
  token: 'abc',
  name: 'thomas'
 },
 ...
]
```

Who can help me please!

Comment: have you made an attempt? try using `.map`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907549/3462319

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.map` will do the trick.

I have made use of object destructuring as well.

```js
const data = [
 { id:1, token: 'xyz', name: 'john', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
 { id: 2, token: 'abc', name: 'thomas', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
];
const output = data.map(({id, name, token}) => ({id, name, token}));
console.log(output);
```

If you have a list of allowed keys. You can incoperate this in the map function. Just loop through this array inside the map and add this to an object.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = [
 { id:1, token: 'xyz', name: 'john', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
 { id: 2, token: 'abc', name: 'thomas', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
];
const list_keys_allowed = ['id', 'token', 'name'];
const output = data.map((node) => {
    const newObj = {};
    list_keys_allowed.forEach(key => newObj[key] = node[key])
    return newObj;
});
console.log(output);
```

The above statements will create a new array from existing.

If you want to update original array, you could follow the below logic.

**Logic**

- Loop through the array.
- Access the nodes from object.
- Loop through the remaining keys and delete them from the objects in the array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, token: 'xyz', name: 'john', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
    { id: 2, token: 'abc', name: 'thomas', _v: 2, _isActived: true, _isBlocked: false },
];
data.forEach((data) => {
    const { id, name, token, ...restNodes } = data; // ...restNodes will collect all keys except id, name and token
    Object.keys(restNodes).forEach((key) => delete data[key]);
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: can you give me an example Array.map() with keys matching from list declared? Ex: const list_keys_allow = ['id', 'token', 'name']

Comment: @Anna Sorry, I couldnt understand. Can you elaborate what you are looking for?

Comment: Ex: 
  const list_keys_allowed = ['id', 'token', 'name'];
  // [ { id:1, token: 'xyz', name: 'john' }]

  const list_keys_allowed = ['id', '_v', '_isBlocked'];
  // [ { id: 1, _v: 2, _isBlocked: false } ]

Comment: @Anna updated the answer, please check

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helps for me learn a lot. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

`const newArray = myArray.map(object => ({object.id, object.token, object.name}))`